# Is the Facebook login process fundamentally different for iOS vs. Android?

Tags: ios, facebook, authentication

[image]I'm an Android programmer and I hired someone to write an iOS version of a Facebook app I wrote. A dispute came up regarding the login process on both platforms. In the Android app, when I log in to the app the first time, I see a screen from Facebook prompting me to continue, but after the first time, I don't see the screen; I just go directly to the app. He claims that under iOS, we can never bypass the Continue screen: it always displays. In his words,

"Tip: In order to clear the login token totally you need to logout from Facebook in safari browser as well since we can't clear that token of safari browser programmatically. it is not permitted on iOS."

Is this true?

EDIT: Here's what my developer replied:

"I didn't explicitly set the login behavior. it should be selected as default value."

and

"The Facebook SDK automatically selects the optimal login dialog flow based on the account settings and capabilities of a person's device. This is the default sequence that the Facebook SDK implements:

Facebook App Native Login Dialog
Facebook App Web Login Dialog
Mobile Safari Login Dialog
If the Facebook account is not set up, the Facebook SDK checks to see if the Facebook app is installed on the device. If the Facebook app is installed, the Facebook app native login dialog is presented if it's supported. If the Facebook app native login dialog can't be displayed because there's an old version of the app, the Facebook app web login dialog is presented. If the Facebook app isn't installed, mobile Safari is launched to display the Mobile Safari login dialog." I'm not clear on how all this is relevant to the issue, though.

Comment: He is correct about the logging out from Safari (I'm not sure what continue button you are talking about at all so I can't say how to bypass it -- perhaps add a Screenshot): https://stackoverflow.com/a/44092474/1462718 . One way is to always use the Modal WebView FBSDKBehaviour instead.. You can try the below as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110740/login-logout-issue-with-facebook-ios-sdk?rq=1 and it MIGHT work (back in 2015 when I tried, it didn't work).. perhaps the SDK has updated since then.

Comment: I don't understand why my programmer is even mentioning logging out from Facebook,  since that's not the issue here.  It's about logging out of the app.

Comment: It depends entirely on how he implemented the SDK. If your developer is using the FBSDKLoginBehaviourWeb, they will be able to log out of your app without any issues. If the developer is using any other FBSDK Behaviour, then it depends on whether or not the native app is installed.. If the native facebook app is installed, logout might still work normally. Otherwise it will always fail and instead your users will need to log out of SAFARI in order to log out of your app (nothing your developer can do to fix this other than the hacks I already posted above).

Comment: Take an iPhone, run your app on it (make sure native facebook app **is not** installed). Log into facebook in your app (OAuth2). Try to log out of your app. Open Safari and go to facebook.com. If you are still logged in, then you understand the problem. Try the same with the native app installed and see the difference. Then ask your developer to use the `FBSDKLoginBehaviourWeb`. Try both scenarios again.

Comment: Here's what my developer replied: